# AWS Serverless - Access Denied After Transferring Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless

Running Python3.8 in AWS Cloud and packaging/deploying via serverless. Have had no issues to date until I transferred my account to another Organization using AWS Organizations. The new Organization basically inherited all of my resources, functions and code. My users have admin privileges for s3, Lambda, API Gateway and DynamoDB as well overall AdministratorAccess.

My functions/services all run fine: API Gateway, Lambda and DynamoDB are not throwing errors when I test or invoke my function. However, when I attempt to make changes to my Lambda function and deploy via serverless, I receive an error "Access Denied". The logs are vague and point to an awsProvider.js file. In the serverless deployment, the error occurs during an S3 putObject call.

Has anyone come across this issue after transferring their account?
[image: Serverless deploy error]

[image: Serverless yml config items]

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that the new Org's policies/restrictions overrode the Account-level access. **Explicit denies override allows.**
[image]